# Are the Ewok movies canonical?

Tags: star-wars, canon, star-wars-legends, ewoks

Are the movies, *Ewoks: The Battle for Endor (1985)*, and *Caravan of Courage - The Ewok Adventure (1984)* considered canonical, or just children's movies that happen to involve a Star Wars license?

Some parts of the movies, such as the Witch, Charal, don't really feel at home with the universe of the three movies.

Comment: -1 for making me go find my mind bleach.

Comment: "On page 155 of the novel Legacy of the Force: Fury, Darth Caedus goes to check on his daughter Allana in a secret compartment of the Anakin Solo, and he finds her sleeping as an "entertainment broadcast in which Ewoks spoke Basic and befriended shipwrecked little girls" plays on a viewscreen". So it's clearly canon in-universe :)

Comment: @DVK: Hey! I like the Ewok movies. At least, I did when I was seven. Surely my tastes haven't changed since.

Comment: @CharlesBurns - Trust me, don't watch them again.

Comment: They're still fun, but not high cinema by any standard. Not much below the original trilogy in quality, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Along with everything that's not one of the six feature films, the Clone Wars TV series and Film, they're now considered to be part of the "Legends" canon.**

> *While Lucasfilm always strived to keep the stories created for the EU
>   consistent with our film and television content as well as internally
>   consistent, Lucas always made it clear that he was not beholden to the
>   EU. **He set the films he created as the canon. This includes the six
>   Star Wars episodes, and the many hours of content he developed and
>   produced in Star Wars: The Clone Wars.** These stories are the immovable
>   objects of Star Wars history, the characters and events to which all
>   other tales must align.*

---

At the time of broadcast they were considered to be fully canonical ('G-Canon') alongside the three original trilogy films. They certainly fit the other [G-Canon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_canon#The_Holocron) criteria in the sense that **Lucas co-wrote and co-directed both films**

On top of that, multiple versions of the DVD, VHS and [Soundtrack CD](http://www.blam1.com/StarWars/G78F5575.htm) feature a quote from Variety Magazine (*"Daily Variety pronounces that Ewoks: The Battle for Endor triumphs as a **worthy entrant into the hallowed Star Wars canon**"*).

[image]

Since then, LucasFilm [steadily downgraded](http://web.archive.org/web/20080602115308/http://www.starwars.com/eu/tv/classic/f20000824/indexp2.html) their status to the current level of "[C-Canon](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Canon)" as part of the Expanded Universe (e.g considered fully canon **unless contradicted elsewhere by the 6 films or Clone Wars TV show**) and since April 2014, they're now considered part of the "Legends" canon.

Answer (score 5):

1. Since Lucasfilm officially authorized their DVD re-issue in 2004, they are canon:

   http://www.ebay.com/bhp/star-wars-ewok-adventures
2. A lot of material from the movies is not only "considered" canon, but is affirmed as such by being re-used in later C-canon EU material.

   Specifically, Teeks, Marauders, Goraxes (Goraxii?), Charal, Blurrgs, and the Towanis have shown up in other books (The Illustrated Star Wars Universe, The Essential Guide to Planets and Moons, and the Black Fleet Crisis (where we see a grown-up Cindel) ([src](http://www.sirstevesguide.com/showthread.php/591-Ewok-movies-canon-or-non-canon/page2)).