# How/Where does "Ewoks: The Battle for Endor" fit into the Star Wars timeline?

Tags: star-wars, production, ewoks, endor

The question [*Are the ewok movies canonical?*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/56016/are-the-ewok-movies-canonical) shows that *The Battle for Endor* is at least canonical to a certain extent.

That being so, where does it fit into the Star Wars main storyline, i.e., the six movies?

By fit in, I mean not only into the story timeline, but also into the franchise. i.e., in a production sense.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the (now defunct) Starwars.com [Expanded Universe page](http://web.archive.org/web/20080602115308/http://www.starwars.com/eu/tv/classic/f20000824/indexp2.html), the two Ewok films take place shortly before the events of Return of the Jedi, citing the lack of Imperial presence on Endor. This would place the films at approx 3ABY (After the Battle of Yavin):

> A timeline published in the Star Wars Insider places the Ewok movies
>   as happening a short time before Return of the Jedi. There is no
>   Imperial presence visible on Endor, suggesting the films take place
>   before the Death Star operation began in earnest. Also, Wicket appears
>   to learn english through his association with Cindel. It is likely
>   that the language Cindel was speaking was not Basic, but another
>   language, and that it was translated into english for the benefit of
>   the viewing audience. Thus, Wicket doesn't understand what Princess
>   Leia is saying when those two meet. Also featured extensively in the
>   films was Ewokese, the language developed by Ben Burtt for the Ewoks.

[image]